# PayPal Button Replacement

Tags: html, forms, button, paypal, hyperlink

Paypal offers a button with the following code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="96FKD7W4CCMEE">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
```

I would prefer to use my own button instead of the paypal "buy now" button offered here. The code for the button I would like is:

```
<div style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;" class="button"><p align="center" style="font-size:30px;">Purchase</p></div>

.button {
background-color:#64A9FD;
padding:20px;
width:200px;
cursor:pointer; 
opacity:0.8;
}
```

How can I substitute paypal's button for my own.

**What I've Tried**:

Nestling my button in between the form start and end tags - paypal's button still showed

Deleting the  tag - the button didn't work at all

Deleting the "src=""" in the  tag - the alternate text linked me to the destination but clicking the button did not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the div an ID of for example mySubmit, **remove the image** since it is named "submit" which will block submission via script (unless you CLICK it) and do

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById("mySubmit").addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    document.querySelector('form').submit();
  });
});
```

assuming the paypal form is the first on the page.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/XqZ6U/)

IF paypal INSISTS on having a button called submit, you can try hiding the form, change the image to a submit button and use

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById("mySubmit").addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    document.querySelector('[name=submit]').click();
  });
});
```

where the querySelector will take the first element named submit on the page

Comment: The paypal form is on the html document within the body. Looking at your code, does having an array of [0] mean the first form that shows up? If I had multiple paypal buttons (i.e. multiple forms on the page), would I give different ids to each div and change the forms[0] to forms[1] etc...?

Comment: so if I had three different forms (going by the order they are listed in the html), if I gave the div button for form 3 an id of mySubmit3

document.getElementById("mySubmit3").onclick=function() {
    document.forms[3].submit();

would work?

Comment: It didn't seem to work, it just added "?search=&bgresponse=" to my url and brought me to the top of the page

Comment: If you have 3 forms, then forms[0].submit will submit the first one and forms[2] the third one. My code should work unless paypal wants a submit=... for the removed image. Submitting a posted form will not load YOUR page with something added to the url. For sure not when the form is targetted _top. I am off to bed

Comment: where should I put the javascript, because I tried putting it in both the head and body but I still get the error

Comment: never mind, it's fixed. I had another array code, so I changed [0] to [1] and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Your button can be reconstructed into a link: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=96FKD7W4CCMEE

How to find it:
https://www.erienewsnow.com/story/41690386/how-to-get-a-paypal-button-url

Added to your code:

```
<div onclick="location.href='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=96FKD7W4CCMEE';" class="button"><p align="center" style="font-size:30px;">Purchase</p></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also do this by jQuery.
Use this code -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('input[type="image"][name="submit"][alt]').replaceWith('<input type="submit" name="submit" id="paypal-btn" value="Buy Now" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">');
});
```

and in your stylesheet.css put these css code for background image

```
#paypal-btn{background:url(images-path);
color:transparent;
}
```

Note: comment the above css code and add your css code given for button.

Comment: NEVER call anything name="submit" in a form and you are not replacing the image with a div shaped like a button here